# Is it possible in JSF to prevent buttons/links and redirects from being executed?

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, jboss7.x, lifecycle

I have some download implementation which allows me to export all data from a dataTable. When a lot of data is being exported, the user must not press anywhere in the application, because the current export process is getting aborted then and it would crash with some exceptions like "EJB Invocation failed on component....." or "Could not find XyzBean".

So my idea is to forbid button presses as long as the download process is in progress. I thought about using a PhaseListener but I'm not sure how to intercept request? The awaited behaviour should be that nothing happens in the GUI when user presses anywhere as long as the download process is in progress. I could set a variable when download has been started and unset it when download has been finished. So I know when to block, but I'm not sure how this blocking could look like. Any ideas?

I'm using JBoss 7.1.1 with RichFaces 4.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution causes a latch for all buttons in the view, so if a download is in progress and I press any buttons, this request will be discarded. This basically works but I still have some crashes with , but I think this is related to another problem.

In my download method at the beginning I add a flag to the current session:

```
HttpSession session = (HttpSession) facesContext.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
session.setAttribute("DOWNLOAD_IN_PROGRESS", "true");
```

At the end of the download method I set this flag to false...

```
session.setAttribute("DOWNLOAD_IN_PROGRESS", "false");
```

In a phase listener (which has been added to faces-config) I check if there is currently a download in progress. If so, discard the request.

```
@Named
@Logged
public class DownloadLatchPhaseListener implements PhaseListener
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8603272654541248512L;

    @Override
    public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event)
    {
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false);

        if (session != null && "true".equals(session.getAttribute("DOWNLOAD_IN_PROGRESS")))
        {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event)
    {
        // not used
    }

    @Override
    public PhaseId getPhaseId()
    {
        return PhaseId.RESTORE_VIEW;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you better use client side solution (its called `BlockUI`) in Primefaces they got this component [BlockUI](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/blockUI.jsf) , but since you are using `RichFaces` and I don't the have it...

You could use the  [jQuery plugin of BlockUI](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/) directly

Comment: I already tried a lot of client side solutions but they never work. The problem is that the GUI is not "connected" to the backing bean anymore. Example: I tried to check for my "downloadFinished" variable in Javascript. This works until the download will be started. Then the GUI somehow thinks that download is finished and the processing dialog disappears although the download process is still in progress. It looks like that there are new instances of the beans but when I set a breakpoint, my variable will be invoked only once as expected. This is very strange, I'm not sure how this happens.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest thing you can do is to use a modal popup panel with a progress bar or some notification while downloading. When a download finishes, you simply close the popup panel.

Here is a sample, however, it defines onmaskclick which you would not want to set:
http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=popup&sample=modalPopup&skin=emeraldTown

Comment: That's not possible in my case (I tried to find Javascript, CDI solutions), because the download response has to call responseComplete() which causes the side effect that the current view looses the "connection" to the backing bean. That means I can't poll/push or access any instance of the backing bean. For example, see one of my attempts here: https://community.jboss.org/thread/201172?tstart=0